# Independence between the minimum of difference of exponentials

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, exponential-distribution

I was reading Stochastic Processes (3rd Edition), by J MEDHI Professor Emeritus Guwahati University Guwahati, India, and find the following result without proofs on P25,

Two independent continuous variables $T_1$, $T_2$ are exponential if and only if
\begin{align*}
 Z=\min \left\{T_1, T_2\right\} \text { and } W=T_1-T_2
\end{align*}
are independent.

I am thinking how to prove $T_1$ and $T_2$ are exponentials through the independence between $Z$ and $W$. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3847093/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4080703/321264.

Comment: Many thanks for the reference. I see it now.