# $\min(X,Y)$ and $X-Y$ with $X,Y$ iid exponential distributions

Tags: probability-theory, density-function, exponential-distribution

Let :

- $X$ and $Y$ be two independent exponential distributions of parameter $\lambda$
- $T=X-Y$
- $Z =\min(X,Y)$

We want to show that $T$ and $Z$ are independant, without any memoryless property.

---

My attempt :

$
\begin{align*}
f_{T}(s) & = \int_{ \mathbb{ R} }^ {} f_X(s-u) f_{-Y}( u) du \\
                 &= \int_{ \mathbb{ R} }^ {} e^{ - \lambda (s-u) } e^{ - \lambda u} \mathbb{1}_{ s-u \geq 0}   \mathbb{1}_{ u \leq 0}   \\
               & = e^{ - \lambda s }   \int_{ \mathbb{ R} }^ {}  e^{ 2 \lambda u}  \mathbb{1}_{ u \leq  (0 \wedge s)} \\
              & = \frac{1} {2}  e^{ - \lambda  (2 (0 \wedge s)     -s  )} \\
             &= \frac{1} {2}  e^{  -  \lambda |s|} \\
\end{align*}
$

$f_Z(z)= 2 e^{- 2 \lambda z}$

$
\begin{cases} 
X-Y <t & \\ 
\min(X,Y) <z\\ 
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases} 
X<t+Y & \\ 
\{ \min(X,Y) <z, Y \leq Z  \} \cup  \{ \min(X,Y) <z, Y \geq Z  \} \\ 
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases} 
\{ X< Y+t ,Y \leq Z  \} \cup \\
 \{ X<z, Y \geq z  \} \\ 
\end{cases}
$

For $t>0$ and $z>0$
$
\begin{align*}
F_W(t,z)&= P(T<t,Z \leq z) \\ &= \int \int \mathbb{1}_{(X-Y) <t , \min(X,Y) <z } dP \\
 &= \int_{0}^{z} \int_{0}^{y+t} f_X(x) dx  f_Y(y) dy + \int_{z}^{ + \infty} \int_{0}^{z} f_X(x) dx ) f_Y(y) dy \\
\end{align*}
$

For $t>0$ and $z>0$, $F_{Z,T}(z,t) =1 - \frac{1}{2} e^{-t}(1- e^{-2z}) - e^{ -2 z} $

For $z >0$ and $t<0$, $ Y \geq X-t$ and $X \leq z$, therefore,

$
\begin{align*}
F_W(t,z) &= \int_{0}^{z} \lambda e^{ - \lambda x}  ( \int_{x-t}^{ + \infty} \lambda e^{ - \lambda y } dy ) dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{z} \lambda e^{ - \lambda x}  e^{ - \lambda (x-t)} \\
&=e^{ \lambda t} \frac{1}{2} (1- e^{ - 2 \lambda z })\\
\end{align*}
$

Comment: "without any memoryless property" - why would you want to do this the hard, unenlightening way, when you can do it the quick, intuitive way?

Comment: Could you write down the intuitive way ? I have corrected my answer, that seems correct now.

Comment: The intuitive way is to use the memoryless property: $Z$ is the waiting time until the first event, $|T|$ is the waiting time until the second event (which is independent from the first waiting time by memorylessness), and the sign of $T$ tells us which of $X$ or $Y$ is larger, which is independent from both of the above by symmetry.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240822/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to prove the PDF is separable.

If $x\ge y$, $z=x$ and $z_x=1,\,z_y=0$. In terms of [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)$$z_x=[x\ge y],\,z_y=1-[x\ge y],$$ so$$\frac{dtdz}{dxdy}=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
\left[x\ge y\right] & 1-\left[x\ge y\right]
\end{array}\right|=1.$$Since $x+y=|t|+2z$, the infinitesimal probability is$$\lambda^2e^{-\lambda(x+y)}dxdy=\tfrac12\lambda e^{-\lambda|t|}dt\cdot2\lambda e^{-2\lambda z}dz.$$This also obtains the distributions of $T\sim\operatorname{Laplace}(0,\,1/\lambda),\,Z\sim\operatorname{Exp}(2\lambda)$.