# Are minimum and difference of two iid exponential random variables independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence, exponential-distribution

Let $Y_{1} = \min(X_{1},X_{2})$, $Y_{2} = \mid X_{1}-X_{2} \mid$, where $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are two independent random variables distributed exponentially with parameter $1$. I want to know if $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are independent.

I've found their distribution functions as follows:

$F(Y_{1} \leq y_{1})$ = $1-e^{-y_{1}/2}$ and $F(Y_{2} \leq y_{2}) = 1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-y_{2}}$, with $y_{2}$ is positive.

But I don't know how to compute the joint distribution

Comment: Do you mean $Y_2 = |X_1 X_2|$? Also, since $X_i$ are exponentially distributed they are necessarily non-negative so you can omit the absolute value.

Comment: Have you already heard of convolution of measures and convolution product ?

Comment: sorry I've just made a mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $U=\operatorname{min}\{X,Y\}$ and $V=\operatorname{max}\{X,Y\}$. Show that $V-U$ is independent of $U$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240822/let-u-operatornamemin-x-y-and-v-operatornamemax-x-y-show-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compute the joint distribution, you can start by computing $\mathbb E\left[\phi(Y_1,Y_2)\right]$ where $\phi\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is measurable and bounded. To do so, observe that $\phi(Y_1,Y_2)$ is a symmetric function of $(X_1,X_2)$, hence
$$
\mathbb E\left[\phi(Y_1,Y_2)\right]=2\mathbb E\left[\phi(X_1,X_2-X_1)\mathbf{1}_{\{X_2>X_1\}}\right].
$$
One can express the previous expectation as a double integral, namely,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\phi(X_1,X_2-X_1)\mathbf{1}_{\{X_2>X_1\}}\right]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \phi(x_1,x_2-x_1)\mathbf{1}_{\{x_2>x_1\}}e^{-x_1-x_2}
dx_2dx_1.$$
Doing the substitution $t=x_2-x_1$ in the inner integral (for a fixed $x_1$) gives
$$\mathbb E\left[\phi(Y_1,Y_2)\right]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \phi(x_1,t)f(x_1,t)dtdx_1$$
for some function $f$ which is the joint density of $(Y_1,Y_2)$.